# ics-openvpn : how to compile on windows machine

Tags: android, batch-file, android-ndk, openvpn

I get the latest source code on here :[ics-openvpn](https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn) and I want to compile it under windows environment. As in `README.txt` said :

> Do cd main;./misc/build-native.(sh|bat) in the root directory of the
>   project. After that build the project using "gradle build" (Or use
>   Android Studio).  The project is converted to gradle and building with
>   Eclipse is no longer supported.

But the content of file `build-native.bat` is:

```
@echo on
echo Currently broken, feel free to fix and send me a patch, see .sh file
exit 1

call ndk-build APP_API=all -j 8


cd libs
mkdir ..\assets
mkdir ..\build\

for /D %%f in (*) do (
    copy %%f\minivpn ..\assets\minivpn.%%f
    del %%f\libcrypto.so
    del %%f\libssl.so

    mkdir ..\build\native-libs\%%f\
    copy %%f\*.so  ..\build\native-libs\%%f\
)

cd ..
```

it means that author notices that this bat file contains error, that cannot be build by this. I try to remove first three lines and run again, i meet these errors:

> main//jni/Android.mk:11: lzo/Android.mk:  no such file or directory
>   main/jni/android.mk : 12: snappy/Android.mk : no such file or
>   directory ...

so, my question is : can we build this library on windows (because author has notified that this build file is error), and if can, how ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just like the text says. It is broken because I don't develop on Windows. You can look at the build-native.sh fix the paths etc for Windows. The build problems are nothing difficult but someone has to take the 10 minutes and fix it.

Comment: thanks for answer from original author :) So, `build-native.sh` will work successfully on linux, right ? so, i can compile on linux, and port those so file to windows again. or, do you know s.o has fix this problem ? thanks :)

Comment: Yeah. That should work but just fixing the paths in the bat file is probably easier

Comment: i try to build on `cygwin` environment, but received error, `command make not found`. akthough i have tested on command promt that i can use `make`. does this error relate to ndk ? thanks :)

Comment: I have another issue. Can you give me a hint, please. Here is my link : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589146/ics-openvpn-process-exit-with-exit-value-1` thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I got all sorts of errors using Cygwin to build this.

You may have more luck using an actual Linux box or something like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) with an [Ubuntu](http://virtualboxes.org/images/ubuntu/) image.

This worked for me. You will need the [Linux NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Downloads) (installation instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Installing)) and you'll need to install make with `sudo apt-get install make`.

Then run `cd main;./misc/build-native.sh` from the project root.

Comment: Then run cd main;./misc/build-native.sh from the project root.

This is extremely important step.
Thanks @gunwin
+1

Comment: I am getting the following error on running this ./misc/build-native.sh: command :

 line 29: /home/ladmin/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build/ndk-build: Permission denied
Any help , please ?

Comment: prefix your command with `sudo`. so `sudo cd main;./misc/build-native.sh`